# Using large ostream tellp() function with large files when position > ULONG_MAX

Tags: c++, std, ostream

I'm trying to store offsets of a file pointing to different positions on it.
Using tellp() function, I can know the actual position in the file, that is, an integer.

The problem comes when this number reaches 4.294.967.295. Overflow appears and then tellp is not showing me a correct number. So, What is the manner of dealing with big (>4GB) files?

Comment: Looking through the GCC C++ library, the positions will be a 64 bit integer if those are supported by the compiler.

Comment: In my case (Intel C++ Compiler) the limit is an ULONG_MAX, that is the same than UINT_MAX, so only 4GB files here. Any tricks?

Comment: Remember that `tellp` doesn't actually return a normal integer, it returns a value of type `pos_type`. And that type is probably a specialization of a `std::fpos` class. Search your library for the `std::fpos` class to really know what type the returned position is.

Comment: numeric_limits<streamoff>::max() returns me 9223372036854775807, but when the limit of 4GB is reached,

 (unsigned long long)(os.tellp())...

"pos" becomes a small number again